# Bizarre result in SQL query - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, union

I discovered this strange behavior with this query:

```
-- TP4N has stock_class = 'Bond'

select  lot.symbol
      , round(sum(lot.qty_left), 4) as "Qty"
  from  ( select  symbol
                , qty_left
--                , amount
            from trade_lot_tbl t01
            where t01.symbol not in (select symbol from stock_tbl where stock_class = 'Cash')
              and t01.qty_left > 0
              and t01.trade_date <= current_date        -- only current trades
           union 
           select  'CASH' as symbol
            , sum(qty_left) as qty_left
--            , sum(amount)   as amount
            from trade_lot_tbl t11
            where t11.symbol in (select symbol from stock_tbl where stock_class = 'Cash')
              and t11.qty_left > 0
              and t11.trade_date <= current_date        -- only current trades
            group by t11.symbol
        ) lot
  group by lot.symbol
  order by lot.symbol
;
```

Run as is,  the Qty for TP4N is 1804.42

Run with the two 'amount' lines un-commented, which as far as I can tell should NOT affect the result, yet Qty for TP4N = 1815.36. Only ONE of the symbols (TP4N) has a changed value, all others remain the same.

Run with the entire 'union' statement commented out results in Qty for TP4N = 1827.17

The correct answer, as far as I can tell, is 1827.17.

So, to summarize, I get three different values by modifying parts of the query that, as far as I can tell, should NOT affect the answer.

I'm sure I'm going to kick myself when the puzzle is solved, this smells like a silly mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely, what you are seeing is caused by the use of `union`. This set operator *deduplicates* the resultsets that are returned by both queries. So adding or removing columns in the `union`ed sets may affect the final resultset (by default, adding more columns reduces the risk of duplication).

As a rule of thumb: unless you *do* want deduplication, you should use `union all` (which is also more efficient, since the database does not need to search for duplicates).

Comment: That fixes it. I will have to review the Union statement.